# SSH Server confirms Client?

Tags: ssh, sftp, file-transfer, tibco

My company uses a commercial (TIBCO MFT) software system to handle file transfers, and I recently encountered an instance where I was unable to connect to a specific clients SFTP server. I could connect all day when going from a Linux terminal on the same local server, but when trying to use the software I failed to authenticate. I am using a simple user/password set up to connect to them.
I eventually fixed this by (in the software control panel) selecting "use default key"(which by the way was OUR key)in SSH options, where the selection had previously been "none". 
To my mind, we should have been required to use *some* sort of key, but it was brought to my attention that we have a lot of SFTP push file transfers that use server configurations with the SSH key marked as "none". 
I have looked around and not found a satisfactory answer. I have my suspicions though:

- Does the *remote server* have a file containing keys for remote systems (sort of like known_hosts?), and
  if a client system is not in that file, they won't even let me log
  in?
- Does this have something to do with the "double key exchange"
  used in SSH2? If a customer server is using SSH1 it would not require my server key?

I would really appreciate any insight in to this.

Answer (score 0):

SSH can be setup to accept both keys and username/password. The target system can easily support both.

You do not have a "known_hosts" file to verify (with keys) which host you connect from. You only verify the host *you* connect *to*. It is however very common to limit access to a host using IP restrictions either via firewall or SSH configuration.

But then you still might access the account on the host using keys.

If the target system is some sort of Unix you will most likely have an account name for accessing it. That user account will most probably have a home directory on the server. In the account home directory you will have a folder named ".ssh" within that folder you have a file named "authorized_keys". You can in this file list any number of public keys for accessing this account. If you have the proper private/public key pair your will then be able to access this account.

So to answer your specific questions:
- No. Such restrictions would be IP based.
- No. Server key is only used to verify the server you connect to.

First key exchange will be to verify the host that you connect to. This is what you are being asked about the first time you connect to a host. When you accept this you have an encrypted session. If allowed you will enter username/password after this. If the host is setup to use key based authentication then you must supply your keys.

Both the SSH client and your SSH server should provide logs with many hints to what happens.

Many Unix servers use OpenSSH and you can see the configuration file at:
/etc/ssh/sshd_config

If you try to connect to a SSH server which requires key based authentication and does not accept username/password then you will typically get the error: "No supported authentication methods avaiable (server sent: public key)".

When using a commercial solution I would however suspect that their ssh stack might be old and outdated and not using the modern cipher suites. You can see what ciphers are used on the Linux server by searching for "Ciphers" in "/etc/ssh/sshd_config"

For further troubleshooting I would recommend to connect directly using putty from the source system. This can easily ferrit out if TIBCO MFT uses an outdated stack and needs updating.

You can get Putty at: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/

To help you further we would need connection logs and configuration files. You should have an connection error which tells us exactly what is wrong.